# What is the Script CMD for add rule for Routing and Remote Access in Firewall?

Tags: firewall, scripting

Does anyone know the script from Command Prompt to add a rule for Routing and Remote Access ?

Routing and Remote Access (GRE-Out)
Routing and Remote Access (L2TP-Out)
Routing and Remote Access (PPTP-Out)

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate about what you are trying to do?  Also what OS? I am assuming Windows, but the version of Windows matters, since the PS commands didn't exist in earlier versions.

If I assume you are talking about a modern version of Windows you would want to look at the commands in the Netsecurity powershell module. Adding a simple Windows firewall usually potentially requires using several Commandlets in conjunction.

Refs

- The output of `Get-Command -Module netsecurity`
- Online docs https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/

Comment: From Firewall I want to add a rule - Routing and Remote Access.
This rule can be added manually, but I want to add it from the command prompt.
I am using Windows 10 Pro 20H2

Comment: To add rules to the Firewall I used the following syntax.

For GRE Protocol - 
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name = "GRE" protocol = 47 dir = in action = allow.

For Netlogon Service (NP-In) - 
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group = "Netlogon Service" new enable = Yes

But I don't know the syntax for Routing and remote Service

Comment: To add manualy, open Control Panel -> Windows Defender Firewall -> Advanced Settings -> Inbound Rules or Outbound Rules -> New Rule -> Predefined -> from drop down list choose Routing and Remote Access -> Next -> Check all checkbox Routing and Remote Access (PPTP-In), Routing and Remote Access (L2TP-In), Routing and Remote Access (GRE-In) -> Next ...

Comment: You can edit your question with additional details.  I can't really follow what you are asking in these comments.